# Return property from object with correct type using generic typing in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generic-programming

I have, many times, tried to implement generic functions that extract properties from an object. The code underneath in Typescript it returns string | number, though I wanted it to know that it will return a string or a number specifically. In plain JS I would know that the code underneath would return a string and react accordingly, so I hope any light to how this can be solved in Typescript can be shed.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const getPropertyByKey = (
  person: Person
) => (
  key: keyof Person
) => person[key];

const person = {
  name: 'Thomas',
  age: 32
};

const property = (person)('name'); // Should realise it is a string
```

Comment: person isn't a function so you can't call it with person('name')
you call it with person.name or person['name']

Comment: I'm not either. I'm calling the second parameter head of the curried function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the partial function generic and it will be able to infer the type of the return value based on the specific string value of `key`.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const getPropertyByKey = (
  person: Person
) => <K extends keyof Person>(
  key: K
) => person[key];

const person = {
  name: 'Thomas',
  age: 32
};

const property = getPropertyByKey(person)('name');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzGlxM1kCuFARtDZEAvsWIIc9ZFzCooWAA7QwATwBCqgNIRVyALzIAFO2TKo2ELXQWcxAJQGAfMgA8W5BAAekEABMMZABrXSwYNEwcJxMSYN1aLQdnM0iQAG0Q1QBdYQkpMBTbXENCWPIqWgByABUACywKOAxKgBpTTm4AZgAmYhFcokkQaUUFczUDGQg5MZUNbV0jc0t7I0ryiEr7FiA)

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the generic K do different than my example? Confusion really. Good catch, gonna use it :-)

Comment: If `key` is `keyof Person`, that type expands to the union of string literals `'name' | 'age'`. But then that means `typeof person[key]` can only be deduced as the union of types `string | number`. However with the type parameter `<K extends keyof Person>`, the generic function infers the specific type of `K` as either `'name'` or `'age'` depending on how `getPropertyByKey()` is called, so it's able to narrow the type of `person[key]` accordingly.

Comment: You should add this to your answer. Good information :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your example

```
function prop<T, V extends keyof T>(val: T, key: V): T[V] {
  return val[key];
}


const prop1 = prop({ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, 'id'); // number
const prop2 = prop({ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, 'name'); // string
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain why the generic understands while the example does not? Its a bit confusing, cause it looks to be the same at first glance.

Comment: @ThomasJohansen I assume your example has some typo in it because it won't compile when I put it in the playground, but basically the function returns `person[key]`, it's just a fancier way of writing it :)

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong. If you are curious though the marked answer post has a playground using the code. The question uses partial function. I am well aware of what it does, the follow up was how typescript derives the right type, as marked answer answered in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to tell TS what you want. It's a bit more verbose:

```
const getPropertyByKey = (person: Person) => (key:any) => 
  "number" === typeof key ? person["age"] : person["name"];
```